# Cannot create and add new contact to contact list

Tags: exm, list-manager

I am using Sitecore.NET 10.1.1 (rev. 005862). I created an empty list in List Manager. When I am trying to create a new contact

[image]

nothing is happened and in the logs I have error:

```
844 11:00:44 ERROR Application error.

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required.

Source: System.Web.Mvc

at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(RequestContext requestContext)

at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)

at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHandlerWrapper.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in custom pipeline - AbortSitecoreForKnownRoutes. The request from api/sitecore was also processing, but is shouldn't be. I updated my code to not process api/sitecore request

```
 public class AbortSitecoreForKnownRoutes : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            var routeCollection = RouteTable.Routes;
            var httpContext = args.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context;
            var routeData = routeCollection.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));

            if (routeData == null || args.Url.ItemPath.Contains("api/sitecore")) return;

            HttpContext.Current.RemapHandler(routeData.RouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext));
            args.AbortPipeline();
        }
    }
```